# MongoDB .NET Core: No array filter found with BulkWrite

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I am trying to perform an update many with BulkWrite with mongodb c# driver.
I have the following code.
I get the error "No array filter found for identifier 'template' in path 'PartialTemplates.$[template]._id'"

```
        var collection = data.Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("TemplateCollection");
        var filter1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("_id", _ids1);
        var filter2 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("_id", _ids2);
        var filter3 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("_id", _ids3);

        var id1Update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
            .Set("PartialTemplates.$[template]._id", _id1);
        var id2Update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
            .Set("PartialTemplates.$[template]._id", _id2);
        var id3Update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
            .Set("PartialTemplates.$[template]._id", _id3);

        var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
        {
            new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("template.Type.Key", "TemplateType")),
        };

        var updateManies = new List<UpdateManyModel<BsonDocument>>
        {
            new UpdateManyModel<BsonDocument>(filter1, id1Update)
            {
                ArrayFilters = arrayFilters
            },
            new UpdateManyModel<BsonDocument>(filter2, id2Update)
            {
                ArrayFilters = arrayFilters
            },
            new UpdateManyModel<BsonDocument>(filter3, id3Update)
            {
                ArrayFilters = arrayFilters
            }
        };

        var result = await collection.BulkWriteAsync(updateManies);
```

One of the documents looks like this

```
            new BsonDocument
            {
                ["_id"] = Guid.Parse("6da07681-bd40-4fad-8c69-221e186ee6ae"),
                ["PartialTemplates"] = new BsonArray
                {
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        ["_id"] = Guid.Parse("0fcb486b-2b30-481e-b44f-388481a9efe1"),
                        ["Type"] = new BsonDocument
                        {
                            ["Key"] = "TemplateType"
                        }
                    },
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        ["_id"] = Guid.Parse("0fcb486b-2b30-481e-b44f-388481a9efe1"),
                        ["Type"] = new BsonDocument
                        {
                            ["Key"] = "WrongKey"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Can you show the document you're trying to modify?

Comment: I added it to the question